# Most idiomatic way to only run React hook if its dependency changed from the last value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a react app consisting of ParentComponent and HelpSearchWindow. On the page for ParentComponent, there is a button that lets you open up a window containing HelpSearchWindow. HelpSearchWindow has an input field and a search button. When an input is typed and search button is clicked, a search is run and results are displayed to the table on the window. The window can be closed. I have set up a react.useEffect() hook with the dependency `[documentationIndexState.searchTerm]` so that the search functionality is only run if the searchTerm changes.

However, the window was not behaving as I expected it to. **Since useEffect() was being called every time the window was opened after it was closed, it would run the search again no matter if the searchTerm in the dependency array was the same.** Because of this, I added another state prop (prevSearchTerm) from ParentComponent to store the last searched term. This way if the window is opened and closed multiple times without a new searchTerm being set, there is no repeat search run.

**My question is, is there a more idiomatic/react-ish way to do this? Any other code formatting pointers are welcome as well**

```
import {
    setSearchTerm,
} from 'documentationIndex.store';

interface Props {
    searchInput: string;
    setSearchInput: (searchInput: string) => void;
    prevSearchTerm: string;
    setPrevSearchTerm: (searchInput: string) => void;
}

export const HelpSearchWindow: React.FC<Props> = props => {
    const documentationIndexState = useSelector((store: StoreState) => store.documentationIndex);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    // Only run search if searchTerm changes
    React.useEffect(() => {
        async function asyncWrapper() {
            if (!documentationIndexState.indexExists) {
                // do some await stuff (need asyncWrapper because of this)
            }
            if (props.prevSearchTerm !== documentationIndexState.searchTerm) {
                // searching for a term different than the previous searchTerm so run search
                // store most recently used searchTerm as the prevSearchTerm
                props.setPrevSearchTerm(props.searchInput);
            }
        }
        asyncWrapper();
    }, [documentationIndexState.searchTerm]); 
    return (
        <input
            value={props.searchInput}
            onChange={e => props.setSearchInput(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button
            onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                dispatch(setSearchTerm(props.searchInput));
            }}
        >
            Search
        </button>
        <SearchTable
            rows={documentationIndexState.searchResults}
        />
    );
};

//--------- Parent Component----------------------------------------
const ParentComponent = React.memo<{}>(({}) => {
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = React.useState(''); // value inside input box
    const [prevSearchTerm, setPrevSearchTerm] = React.useState(''); // tracks last searched thing
    return(
        <HelpSearchWindow
            searchInput={searchInput}
            setSearchInput={setSearchInput}
            prevSearchTerm={prevSearchTerm}
            setPrevSearchTerm={setPrevSearchTerm}
        />
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the given context, the use of useEffevt hook is redundant. You should simply use a click handler function and attach with the button.

The click handler will store the search term locally in the component and also check if the new input value is different. If it is itll update state and make the api call.